# Flutter Text Widget with padding is larger than expected

Tags: flutter

[image]

As the image above,I have create a text wrap in a container with padding property.The Text Widget has blue color, and the real text size is smaller than the Text Widget size(because of the line truncate).Therefore,the right padding is larger than the left padding.

How can I set an accurate padding to a Text Widget?

Here is my sample code and sample image.

But please note that the right margin is related to your screen size, you may need to adjust the characters to see the problem.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, top: 120, right: 10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.black.withAlpha(100),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(2),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(20)),
            ),
            // width: textSize.width,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 12),
              child: DecoratedBox(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
                child: Text(
                  'a very long qwqwjj爱思大数据那是阿萨德撒啊实打请问去凄凄切切实爱思打',
                  textWidthBasis: TextWidthBasis.longestLine,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    background: Paint()..color = Colors.yellow,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share the code for this please ?

Comment: @MichaelSoliman yes

Comment: @MichaelSoliman ,sample code is shared.

Comment: just try to replace EdgeInsets.symmetric by EdgeInsets.all

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's due to your text. You can wrap text widget with center to place it in center.

Answer (score 0):

When there is available space at the end, the characters will try to fit itself in it, if it didn't fit, it will go to the next line, and the space will remain empty, to make this space split evenly at both sides of the text,
add the `textAlign` property and set it to `TextAlign.center`,

```
Text(
    'a very long qwqwjj爱思大数据那是阿萨德撒啊实打请问去凄凄切切实爱思打',
    style: TextStyle(
       background: Paint()..color = Colors.yellow,
    ),
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
),
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the central layout doesn't fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your Container child to Center and can align text to center

Answer (score 0):

At first,I tried to calculate text size before layout.

```
Size calculateTextHeight(
    String value, double fontSize, FontWeight fontWeight, double maxWidth,
    {int maxLines = 99}) {
  TextPainter painter = TextPainter(
      maxLines: maxLines,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      text: TextSpan(
          text: value,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: fontWeight,
            fontSize: fontSize,
          )));
  painter.layout(maxWidth: maxWidth);
  List<LineMetrics> a = painter.computeLineMetrics();
  var _maxWidth =
      a.reduce((current, next) => current.width > next.width ? current : next);
  return Size(_maxWidth.width + 1, painter.height);
}
```

This method has a little trick,but it works.The size just fits the right text size.Then use `Container` with width and height wraping the `Text`.

Later, I found a better way.Use the `Text`'s `textWidthBasis` property:`textWidthBasis:TextWidthBasis.longestLine`.

[image]